# Complete a change to a cell during a macro button call

Tags: excel, vba, button

I am working on a spreadsheet tool that queries a SQL Server database and populates various sheets with the results. I provide the user with a simple GUI (formatted cells) to enter their database credentials and an Excel form button which tests the connection. When the button is pressed and the connection string is formed correctly, I identify this by changing the color of a status indicator from red to green. I have added a check to the range of cells that hold the credentials using the Worksheet_Change function, which will switch the status from green back to red if any of the cells are altered.

The problem is users are entering some aspect of their connection string, maybe the last field, and then pressing the 'Test Connection' button without first pressing enter or navigating away. and actually writing the value to the cell. My 'Test Connection' macro (linked to the button) is called first, switching the status indicator to green (assuming correct credentials), but the Worksheet_Change method does not get called until after the button macro has run through. The result is that the status indicator blinks from green and then back to red despite a establishing a database connection successfully.

I have tried things like manually switching the focus away from the current cell. Before calling my 'TestConnection' function from the form button. But so far nothing has worked.

Edit: Some Code...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call SetGlobals

    'Check if database criteria has changed
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range(DB_CELL_RANGE)) Is Nothing Then
        Call UpdateDBStatus(1)
    End If

End Sub

'Connect to database using Main sheet credentials
Function TestConnection()

    'Connection vars
    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

    'Open the connection.
    On Error GoTo ConnectError
    cnn.Open GetConnectionString()

    'Update dependencies
    'On Error GoTo FilterError
    Call UpdateFilter("select ********", "F", "F")
    Call UpdateFilter("select *******", "E", "E")
    Call UpdateDBStatus(2)

    MsgBox "Connected successfully to '" & DBASE & "' on machine '" & SERVER & "'"
    'Cleanup
    cnn.Close
    Set cnn = Nothing

    Exit Function

ConnectError:
    Call UpdateDBStatus(1)
    MsgBox "Could not establish a connection."
    Exit Function

FilterError:
    MsgBox "Filter Update Failure."
    Exit Function

End Function

'Set the status of the database connection and mark the result
Public Function UpdateDBStatus(Status As Integer)
    If Status = 1 Then
        Sheets("Main").Range(DB_STATUS_CELL).Value = "Not Connected"
        Sheets("Main").Range(DB_STATUS_CELL).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        DB_STATUS = False
    Else
        Sheets("Main").Range(DB_STATUS_CELL).Value = "Connected"
        Sheets("Main").Range(DB_STATUS_CELL).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        DB_STATUS = True
    End If
End Function
```

Basically if someone is currently editing a cell inside of DB_CELL_RANGE and they presses the 'Test Connection' button I would like to have Worksheet_Change complete before calling 'TestConnection'.

Comment: You should show us some code so that we could understand what we could do

Comment: In a quick test in Excel 2007, it wasn't possible to click on either a forms or ActiveX button while a cell is in edit mode.  Do you have some other kind of button?  Or maybe a different Excel version?

Comment: @Tim I am using Excel 2010 and a form button

Comment: @User - yes, I see that too in 2010: wonder what else that change will break? One solution for your problem might be to store the parameters for any successful connection in global variables, then during the event triggered by the worksheet change, check to see if any of them are changed, and if so only then change your status flag cell.

Comment: @Tim I am toying with a solution like the one you suggested. My status variable is global now, and if you look at my `Worksheet_Change` I think I am attempting to do what you are talking about. The tricky part seems to be telling the difference between a change to a cell, versus a button click coming from an altered cell... if that makes sense.

Comment: What happens in `SetGlobals` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer turned out to be a fairly simple boolean flag which I set to True when a successful database connection is established, then false after the next run of `Worksheet_Change` *finishes*. From then only check the DB connection when the flag is false. Code is as follows:

```
Public flag As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not flag Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range(DB_CELL_RANGE)) Is Nothing Then
            UpdateDBStatus (1)
        End If
    Else
        flag = False
    End If
End Sub

'Connect to database using Main sheet credentials
Sub TestConnection()

    'Connection vars
    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

    'Open the connection.
    On Error GoTo ConnectError
    cnn.Open GetConnectionString()

    'Update dependencies
    On Error GoTo FilterError
    Call UpdateFilter("select ********", "F", "F")
    Call UpdateFilter("select *******", "E", "E")
    Call UpdateDBStatus(2)

    flag = True

    MsgBox "Connected successfully to '" & DBASE & "' on machine '" & SERVER & "'"
    'Cleanup
    cnn.Close
    Set cnn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this is you can disable the 'test connection' button by default.
But either way you're not going to get around that 'worksheet change' being activated after, so I'd just not use it and use a custom function.

**Update:**
After reviewing your code I've included code below the demonstrates what I'm talking about.

I re-wrote your validation check and call it at the start of the test only, and to loop through the validation range.

I also removed the update Status and pasted it throughout the code with more detailed messages. (including notes about the two error sections)

```
Sub TestConnection()

    Call ValidateInput

    If DB_STATUS Then
        'Connection vars
        Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

        'Open the connection.
        On Error GoTo ConnectError 
'-Have ConnectError set the DB-STATUS_Cell to 'Error' and dbstatus to False, cell to red, ect.
        cnn.Open GetConnectionString()

        'Update dependencies
        'On Error GoTo FilterError 
'-Have FilterError set the DB-STATUS_Cell to 'Error' and dbstatus to False, cell to red, ect.
        Call UpdateFilter("select ********", "F", "F")
        Call UpdateFilter("select *******", "E", "E")

        Sheets("Main").Range(DB_STATUS_CELL).Value = "Connected"


        MsgBox "Connected successfully to '" & DBASE & "' on machine '" & SERVER & "'"
        'Cleanup
        cnn.Close
        Set cnn = Nothing
    Else
        MsgBox "Please be sure that you populate all fields", vbExclamation

Exit Sub

Public Sub ValidateInput()
    Dim rCell As Range

    'assuming the named range 'DB_CELL_RANGE' contains all of the input cells you want populated
    For Each rCell In Worksheet.Range(DB_CELL_RANGE)
        If rCell.Value = "" Then
            Sheets("Main").Range(DB_STATUS_CELL).Value = "Not Connected"
            Sheets("Main").Range(DB_STATUS_CELL).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            DB_STATUS = False
            Exit Sub
        Else
            'keep checking range
        End If

        '- If we make it here, then all of the inputs are validated
        Sheets("Main").Range(DB_STATUS_CELL).Value = "Inputs Good, Testing Connection."
        Sheets("Main").Range(DB_STATUS_CELL).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        DB_STATUS = True

    Next rCell

End Sub
```

Note: 
Assuming that `DB_STATUS` is a global variable that signifies if the connection can be tested.
Also, I noticed you declared these as functions, but they didn't seem to return any values so I wrote my versions as Subroutines.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am getting a "424 Object required" error in ValidateInput() on this line: `For Each rCell In Worksheet.Range(DB_CELL_RANGE)`  I am a VBA newb at this point. Do you know what is wrong? I tried declaing rCell as an object and by giving Worksheet.Range a static cell address.

Comment: Replace 'DB_CELL_RANGE' With the range of cells that you dont want to be empty. (Assuming they are all in a row `DB_CELL_RANGE` could become `B3:B5`) If your cells are all spaces out, then I / someone can help modify that code to work that way. I only assumed they were next to eachother due to the existing named range.

Comment: I have tried exactly as you suggested but I am still getting the 424 error. The stepper shows that I have a Range that is in, what I understand to be, the correct cell format [picture](http://i.imgur.com/aSOVs.png). I'm guessing this is something small... it is saying that `rCell=Nothing` any ideas? My DB_CELL_RANGE is a single column but I have tried giving your `For Each` two dimensional ranges, a single row multiple columns etc.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but you should see the general idea...

```
Public LastGoodConnString As String  'this in a regular module

'worksheet module
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range(DB_CELL_RANGE)) Is Nothing Then
        CheckConnString 'Check if database criteria has changed
    End If
End Sub



'Connect to database using Main sheet credentials
Function TestConnection()

    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

    'Open the connection.
    On Error GoTo ConnectError
    cnn.Open GetConnectionString()
    ShowDBStatus True 'this will also cache the connection string...

    '<snipped code>

    Exit Function

ConnectError:
    ShowDBStatus False
    MsgBox "Could not establish a connection."
    Exit Function

End Function

'update DB Status if connection string is changed from a "known good" value
Public Sub CheckConnString()
    ShowDBStatus (GetConnectionString() = LastGoodConnString) _
                     And LastGoodConnString <> ""
End Sub


'Show the status of the database connection
Public Sub ShowDBStatus(StatusOK As Boolean)

    'if connected OK, remember the connection string
    If StatusOK Then LastGoodConnString = GetConnectionString()

    With Sheets("Main").Range(DB_STATUS_CELL)
        .Value = IIf(StatusOK, "Connected", "Not Connected")
        .Interior.ColorIndex = IIf(StatusOK, 4, 3)
    End With

End Sub
```